# Can't make AutoSelectCertificateForUrls work

Tags: google-chrome, automation, certificate

I'm trying to eliminate certificate popups on chrome.

The URL that im trying to automate is: **https://www.sefaz.rs.gov.br/Login/LoginEcacCert.aspx**

I tried:

```
{"pattern": "https://www.sefaz.rs.gov.br/Login/LoginEcacCert.aspx", "filter" : "My_certificate_Name"}
{"pattern": "https://www.sefaz.rs.gov.br", "filter" : "My_certificate_Name"}
{"pattern": "https://[*.].rs.gov.br", "filter" : "My_certificate_Name"}
```

as

```
{"pattern": "[*.]", "filter" : "My_certificate_Name"}
```

and none of that seems to work, how can i make it work?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need:

```
{"pattern": "[*.]", "filter" : {"ISSUER": {"CN":"My_certificate_Name"} } }
```